# Angular decorators issue

Tags: angular, angular-decorator

I have a component in two different projects (project A, Project B), but only works as expected in project A

the following code corresponds to the same block of code for the component

project A

```
    __decorate([
        core_1.ViewChildren(offset_top_directive_1.OffsetTopDirective),
        __metadata("design:type", typeof (_a = typeof core_1.QueryList !== "undefined" && core_1.QueryList) === "function" ? _a : Object)
    ], MyGridComponent.prototype, "offsetItems", void 0);
```

project B

```
    tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__decorate"]([
        Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["ViewChildren"])(app_shared_directives_offset_top_directive__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__["OffsetTopDirective"]),
        tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__metadata"]("design:type", _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["QueryList"])
    ], MyGridComponent.prototype, "offsetItems", void 0);
```

I can't identify why project B is generating code like

`tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__decorate"]...`

instead of

`__decorate([...`

project A - tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Project B - tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

Could any reference, dependency or configuration might be missing in project B ?
any hint ?

Comment: Are the tsconfig.json files identical? Angular versions? Angular.json?

Comment: @David added both tsconfig.json

Comment: The target and  lib properties ara different. Changing them works for you?